# Converting CombinedGeometry Path to Polygon

Tags: c#, wpf, path, polygon

I have this code to add two shapes using combined geometry that works well to create a path object. i'm trying to convert the path to a polygon and this works with rectangles but not with ellipses. i've marked the new part where i'm converting to polygon below with // Conversion Here ********

I would appreciate if someone could please advise why this is not working with ellipses and how i could make this work with all shapes.

here's the code:

```
public void AddShapes()
{
    try
    {

        double ZOrderNum = 2000;
        FrameworkElement elementMain = new FrameworkElement();
        List<double> lstZOrders = new List<double>();

        //Get the Back index
        foreach (FrameworkElement feObject in MainWindow.Data.SelectedObjects)
        {
            lstZOrders.Add(Canvas.GetZIndex(feObject));
            if (Canvas.GetZIndex(feObject) < ZOrderNum)
            {
                ZOrderNum = Canvas.GetZIndex(feObject);
                elementMain = feObject;
            }
        }

        int TotalElements = MainWindow.Data.SelectedObjects.Count;

        FrameworkElement feMain = elementMain;

        TranslateTransform transMain = new TranslateTransform();
        TranslateTransform transSubtract = new TranslateTransform();


        RectangleGeometry geomMainRect = new RectangleGeometry();
        RectangleGeometry geomSubtractRect = new RectangleGeometry();
        EllipseGeometry geomMainEllipse = new EllipseGeometry();
        EllipseGeometry geomSubtractEllipse = new EllipseGeometry();
        PathGeometry geomMainPath = new PathGeometry();
        PathGeometry geomSubtractPath = new PathGeometry();
        LineGeometry geomMainLine = new LineGeometry();
        LineGeometry geomSubtractLine = new LineGeometry();

        GeometryGroup geomGroup = new GeometryGroup();

        //Main Geometry
        transMain = feMain.RenderTransform as TranslateTransform;
        if (feMain is Rectangle)
        {
            geomMainRect = new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(0, 0, feMain.Width, feMain.Height));
        }
        if (feMain is Ellipse)
        {
            geomMainEllipse = new EllipseGeometry(new Rect(0, 0, feMain.Width, feMain.Height));
        }
        if (feMain is Canvas)
        {
            Canvas canvasPath = feMain as Canvas;
            if (canvasPath.Children.Count > 0)
            {
                if (canvasPath.Children[0] is Path)
                {
                    Path pathMain = canvasPath.Children[0] as Path;
                    geomMainPath = pathMain.Data.GetFlattenedPathGeometry();
                }
                if (canvasPath.Children[0] is Polygon)
                {
                    Polygon pathMain = canvasPath.Children[0] as Polygon;
                    geomMainPath = PolygonGemoetry(pathMain);
                }
            }
        }

        TranslateTransform transCheckSub = new TranslateTransform(2000, 2000);
        foreach (FrameworkElement feObject in MainWindow.Data.SelectedObjects)
        {
            if (feObject != feMain)
            {
                //Add to Subtract Geometry Group
                transSubtract = feObject.RenderTransform as TranslateTransform;
                if (transCheckSub.X < transSubtract.X)
                {
                    transCheckSub.X = transSubtract.X;
                }
                if (transCheckSub.Y < transSubtract.Y)
                {
                    transCheckSub.Y = transSubtract.Y;
                }
                transCheckSub = transSubtract;
                if (feObject is Rectangle)
                {
                    geomSubtractRect = new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(transSubtract.X - transMain.X, transSubtract.Y - transMain.Y, feObject.Width, feObject.Height));
                    geomGroup.Children.Add(geomSubtractRect);
                }
                if (feObject is Ellipse)
                {
                    geomSubtractEllipse = new EllipseGeometry(new Rect(transSubtract.X - transMain.X, transSubtract.Y - transMain.Y, feObject.Width, feObject.Height));
                    geomGroup.Children.Add(geomSubtractEllipse);
                }
                if (feObject is Line)
                {
                    Line line = feObject as Line;
                    geomSubtractLine = new LineGeometry(new Point(line.X1, line.Y1), new Point(line.X2, line.Y2));
                    geomGroup.Children.Add(geomSubtractLine);
                }
                if (feObject is Canvas)
                {
                    Canvas canvasPath = feObject as Canvas;
                    if (canvasPath.Children.Count > 0)
                    {
                        if (canvasPath.Children[0] is Path)
                        {
                            Path pathSubtract = canvasPath.Children[0] as Path;
                            geomSubtractPath = pathSubtract.Data.GetFlattenedPathGeometry();
                            geomGroup.Children.Add(geomSubtractPath);
                        }
                        if (canvasPath.Children[0] is Polygon)
                        {
                            Polygon pathSubtract = canvasPath.Children[0] as Polygon;
                            geomSubtractPath = PolygonGemoetrySubtract(pathSubtract, transMain, transSubtract);
                            geomGroup.Children.Add(geomSubtractPath);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //Put it all together               
        CombinedGeometry cg = new CombinedGeometry();
        cg.GeometryCombineMode = GeometryCombineMode.Union;

        //Main Background Paths
        if (geomMainRect.Bounds.Width > 0)
        {
            cg.Geometry1 = geomMainRect;
        }
        if (geomMainEllipse.Bounds.Width > 0)
        {
            cg.Geometry1 = geomMainEllipse;
        }
        if (geomMainPath.Bounds.Width > 0)
        {
            cg.Geometry1 = geomMainPath;
        }

        //Subtract Paths
        cg.Geometry2 = geomGroup;
        geomGroup.FillRule = FillRule.EvenOdd;

        System.Windows.Shapes.Path myPath = new System.Windows.Shapes.Path();
        myPath.Data = cg;
        if (feMain is Rectangle)
        {
            Rectangle rect = feMain as Rectangle;
            myPath.Fill = rect.Fill;
            myPath.Stroke = rect.Stroke;
            myPath.StrokeThickness = rect.StrokeThickness;
        }
        if (feMain is Ellipse)
        {
            Ellipse rect = feMain as Ellipse;
            myPath.Fill = rect.Fill;
            myPath.Stroke = rect.Stroke;
            myPath.StrokeThickness = rect.StrokeThickness;
        }
        if (feMain is Canvas)
        {
            Canvas canvasPath = feMain as Canvas;
            if (canvasPath.Children.Count > 0)
            {
                if (canvasPath.Children[0] is Path)
                {
                    Path rect = canvasPath.Children[0] as Path;
                    myPath.Fill = rect.Fill;
                    myPath.Stroke = rect.Stroke;
                    myPath.StrokeThickness = rect.StrokeThickness;
                }
                if (canvasPath.Children[0] is Polygon)
                {
                    Polygon rect = canvasPath.Children[0] as Polygon;
                    myPath.Fill = rect.Fill;
                    myPath.Stroke = rect.Stroke;
                    myPath.StrokeThickness = rect.StrokeThickness;
                }
            }
        }
        myPath.Name = "NewPath";
        myPath.Name = "Object" + MainWindow.Data.TotalObjects.ToString();
        myPath.Uid = "Object" + MainWindow.Data.TotalObjects.ToString() + "-" + MainWindow.Data.NewZIndex.ToString();
        myPath.Tag = "No";

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
        canvas.Name = "Object" + MainWindow.Data.TotalObjects.ToString();
        canvas.Uid = "Object" + MainWindow.Data.TotalObjects.ToString() + "-" + MainWindow.Data.NewZIndex.ToString();
        canvas.Tag = "No";
        canvas.Width = myPath.Data.Bounds.Width;
        canvas.Height = myPath.Data.Bounds.Height;

        //Get the left and top most transforms
        canvas.RenderTransform = transMain;
        //      canvas.Children.Add(myPath);


        // Conversion Here **************   Convert the path to Polygon ***************************
        if (myPath.Data.GetFlattenedPathGeometry().Figures[0].Segments[0] is PolyLineSegment)
        {
            List<Point> pc = new List<Point>();
            pc.Add(myPath.Data.GetFlattenedPathGeometry().Figures[0].StartPoint);
            pc.AddRange((myPath.Data.GetFlattenedPathGeometry().Figures[0].Segments[0] as PolyLineSegment).Points);
            Polygon pGon = new Polygon();
            pGon.Fill = myPath.Fill;
            pGon.StrokeThickness = myPath.StrokeThickness;
            pGon.Stroke = myPath.Stroke;
            foreach (Point pt in pc)
            {
                pGon.Points.Add(pt);
            }
            //pGon.Points = pc;
            canvas.Children.Add(pGon);
        }

        MainWindow.Data.NewZIndex++;
        MainWindow.Data.TotalObjects++;

        //Add a Scale Transform for resizing
        ScaleTransform scale = new ScaleTransform(1, 1);
        myPath.RenderTransform = scale;

        //Add the new Path
        MainWindow.Data.canvasDrawing[MainWindow.Data.CurrentFrame].Children.Add(canvas);

        //Clean Up
        MainWindow.Data.canvasDrawing[MainWindow.Data.CurrentFrame].Children.Remove(feMain);
        for (int i = 0; i < MainWindow.Data.SelectedObjects.Count; i++)
        {
            FrameworkElement feObject = MainWindow.Data.SelectedObjects[i];
            MainWindow.Data.canvasDrawing[MainWindow.Data.CurrentFrame].Children.Remove(feObject);
        }
        MainWindow.SelectActions.DeselectAllObjects();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

<< Some Images Update: >>

This is the 2 shapes to subtract:

[image]

And this is what i get as a Path:
[image]

And this is what i get as a Polygon:
[image]

Not sure why when the points list has over 20 points. Still at a loss.

<< Update >>
    Changed the conversion code to this but it is one polygon with one start point and one end point.

```
//Convert Path to Polygon
List<Point> pc = new List<Point>();

PathGeometry g = myPath.Data.GetFlattenedPathGeometry();

foreach (var f in g.Figures)
    foreach (var s in f.Segments)
        if (s is PolyLineSegment)
            foreach (var pt in ((PolyLineSegment)s).Points)
            {
                pc.Add(pt);
            }

Polyline pGon = new Polyline();
pGon.Fill = myPath.Fill;
pGon.StrokeThickness = myPath.StrokeThickness;
pGon.Stroke = myPath.Stroke;
foreach (Point pt in pc)
{
    pGon.Points.Add(pt);
}
canvas.Children.Add(pGon);
```

Comment: This is too much code. You should try to reduce it to a minimum working example that reveals the problem. I did a quick test by calling GetFlattenedPathGeometry on an EllipseGeometry, and it returns a PathGeometry with *eight PolyLineSegments* in one PathFigure. Maybe you should check for more than one segment and take all of them into account.

Comment: And I guess it would also make sense not to call `myPath.Data.GetFlattenedPathGeometry()` multiple times, but just assign the outcome to a local variable to avoid multiple calculations of the same data.

Comment: Thanks Clemens, let me try that. I know it's a lot of code but i wanted to be clear. cheers.

Comment: Can't seem to add another section to show some changes

Comment: It looks like this needs to find out how many individual shapes are going to result and create multiple polygons as my new code for the conversion now creates just the one polygon that looks better but not quite right. Can't seem to post the new code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following method copies all points from the PolyLineSegments in a PathFigure into a single PointCollection.

```
using System.Linq;
...

private static PointCollection GetPolylinePoints(PathFigure figure)
{
    var points = new PointCollection();
    points.Add(figure.StartPoint);

    foreach (var segment in figure.Segments.OfType<PolyLineSegment>())
    {
        foreach (var point in segment.Points)
        {
            points.Add(point);
        }
    }

    return points;
}
```

Now you could create a set of Polygons from the PathGeometry returned by GetFlattenedPathGeometry like this:

```
var geometry = myPath.Data.GetFlattenedPathGeometry();

foreach (var figure in geometry.Figures)
{
    var polyline = new Polygon
    {
        Fill = myPath.Fill,
        Stroke = myPath.Stroke,
        StrokeThickness = myPath.StrokeThickness,
        Points = GetPolylinePoints(figure)
    };

    canvas.Children.Add(polyline);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. i found something similar on here that actually works likes yours. couldn't post it so i added an Update earlier. too long or something. What i'm finding now is that when the path is made up of multiple shapes, the polygon is a continuous line and all gets messed up trying to create the polygon from the path. Still trying to work this out. thanks again for your efforts.

Comment: Of course all this only works on a contiguous shape. If the CombinedGeometry contains two unconnected shapes, you will need to create two Polygons. Maybe you should change your approach to create one Polygon from each Figure in the PathGeometry.

Comment: That made so much sense. i tried that but i only seem to be getting 1 figure. i assume that's the whole path. It works if the shape to subtract is half outside of the main shape but just leaves it there if it's inside.

Comment: Sorry. Just found that sometimes there are the number of figures there should be so when subtracting a shape from another shape that creates the path and trying to convert to polygon, 2 polygons are created of the same colour so it looks like nothing happens. i'm thinking that converting to polygons might not be the answer here.

Comment: I'll mark this as answered as I don't believe i'll be able to get this how I want. Thanks for your time. Appreciated. I did learn a few things though.